# Any alternatives to Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: vector-graphics

Are there any open source alternatives to adobe illustrator? I need to make and edit some vector graphics I have, Inkscape is an alternative but when I go to their website they don't seem to have a dmg file (I'm a mac user).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search for "inkscape for mac" provided a top-linked result to the download page. The indication is for a dmg file:

[Mac download page](https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.2/mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape latest version:

> https://inkscape.org/release/0.92.4/mac-os-x/

another open-source project i would recommend:

> https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/
>
> https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/install-howto/macos/

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [Gravit Designer](https://www.designer.io/en/). It isn't open source, but it is free to use. It can be used in a browser or locally installed. I find it much, much easier to figure out than Inkscape. I've also had a lot of problems getting Inkscape to run reliably on a Macintosh and the user interface is not at all native-like. Just for the record, I have no affiliation with the publisher of Gravit Designer.